# Insert a character in the filename

Tags: swift, macos

I want to insert a suffix in the name of a file (.jpg) I loaded. Say the original filename is "AAA.jpg" and the user specified a suffix like "changed", I want to save in the same folder a new file named "AAA changed.jpg". Here is what I tried:

```
var noExt = chosenFiles[indexInChoseFiles].deletingPathExtension() // full_path/filename (but PercentEncoding)
let aString=noExt.absoluteString + " " + filenameSuffix + ".jpg"   // insert the suffix and the extension
var bString=aString.removingPercentEncoding!                       // get rid of PercentEncoding
var newPath=URL(string: bString)                                   // *** nil ***
newPath=URL(string: aString)                                       // *** nil ***
```

aString and bString are OK, but newPath returns nil in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost never should use `.absoluteString` for the manipulation
of URLs, and removing the percent encoding makes it an invalid
URL string, so that the conversion back to `URL` fails.

Here is a simplified demonstration of the problem:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/my documents/aaa.jpg")
let path = url.absoluteString             // "file:///path/to/my%20documents/aaa.jpg"
let path2 = path.removingPercentEncoding! // "file:///path/to/my documents/aaa.jpg"
let url2 = URL(string: path2)             // nil
```

---

One possible solution is to use `.path` instead:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/my documents/aaa.jpg")
print(url)
// "file:///path/to/my%20documents/aaa.jpg"

let path = url.deletingPathExtension().path
let newPath = path + " CHANGED" + ".jpg"
let newURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: newPath)

print(newURL)
// file:///path/to/my%20documents/aaa%20CHANGED.jpg
```

Another solution, using only `URL` methods:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/my documents/aaa.jpg")
print(url)
// "file:///path/to/my%20documents/aaa.jpg"

let ext = url.pathExtension // "jpg"
let basename = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent // "aaa"

let newUrl = url.deletingLastPathComponent()
    .appendingPathComponent(basename + " CHANGED")
    .appendingPathExtension(ext)

print(newUrl)
// "file:///path/to/my%20documents/aaa%20CHANGED.jpg"
```

Comment: That's a perfect and complete answer. Thank you very much, Martin.